# obj-c method error - promise block with string input

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to define a method that takes my time string and type string and sends back the resolved query.
I keep running into the below error (see screenshot)
Am i defining the method correctly???

swift file:

```
@objc(getHeartRate:type:resolver:rejecter:)
func getHeartRate( _ time: String, type: String, resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
            
//query code.....................

resolve(query)

}
```

Finally exporting the method to my front-end javascript:

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getHeartRate: (NSString*)time
                                (NSString*)type
                                resolver: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                                rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with my RCT_EXTERN_METHOD

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getHeartRate: (NSString*)time
                                type:     (NSString*)type      //added type
                                resolver: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                                rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```